# Find the area under the curve $y=√4-x$, i.e find $∫√4-x$ between $x=0, x=4$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The answer I get is $8/3$ but the answer in the book, and when I put in the equation in Geogebra gives me $16/3$. I can't figure what the error in my logic is.

Thanks!

Comment: It’s difficult to find the fault in your logic when you don’t even say what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the reverse power rule, we get that the indefinite integral is $-\dfrac{2}{3} (4-x)^{3/2}.$ Evaluating this integral from $0$ to $4$ gives $0-(-\dfrac{2}{3} 4^{3/2})=\dfrac{16}{3}.$ Your mistake was that you forgot to account for the "$2$" in $\dfrac{2}{3}.$

Comment: I was trying to evaluate $√(4-x)$ giving me $2 - √x$, before finding the integral and getting led astray. I hadn't worked out an integral in this form so my instinct was to turn it into a form I knew.

Comment: so the error in your logic was that you evaluated the wrong integral